# Dropdown menu is cut off at certain resolutions

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive navigation menu for a client. Most of it works except for a problem I'm encountering on mobile devices where the menu list is cut off from the page.

The idea is that the links belong to an inline list, and as the viewport becomes smaller, they are hidden and a menu button is displayed. Tapping the menu button will display a regular (vertical) list beneath it by adding the class "open".

Here is some code:

```js
/* Incomplete code, but basically fixes the header to the top of the page */
if(window.orientation === '0') {
  if(!header.hasClass('scrolling')) {
    header.addClass('scrolling scroll-fixed');
  }
} else if(window.orientation === '90' || window.orientation === '-90') {
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    header.removeClass('scroll-fixed');
  } else {
    header.removeClass('scrolling scroll-fixed');
  }
}
```

```css
/* This is how it will display when toggled */
ul#navigation-links.open {
  display:  block;
  padding:  0 1em;

  background-color: $white;
  box-shadow:       1px 1px 4px #919191;

  list-style-type:  none;
  text-transform:   uppercase;
  font-size:        10pt;

  border:                     1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-bottom-left-radius:  5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;

  li {
    @include headline-stack;

    margin: 0;

    display: block;

    width: 100%;

    a, a:visited {
      margin:  0;
      padding: 0;
      color: $cobalt;
      text-shadow: 2px 1px 3px #f1f1f1;
    }

    a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: $cobalt;
      text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #f1f1f1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a role="button" class="toggle-navigation-links">
    <span>
      Menu &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-bars fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
  </a>

  <ul id="navigation-links">
    <li><a href="/progress/index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/progress/about-us">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/progress/team">Our Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="/progress/services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="/progress/listings">Listings</a></li>
    <li><a href="/progress/community">Community Links</a></li>
    <li><a href="/progress/property">Retail</a></li>
    <li><a href="/progress/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm not sure if this is enough data, but if anyone has advice as to how I could keep the current functionality, but fix this problem, that would be great.

I tried setting a fixed height and making it scrollable, but my project manager wants to avoid this, so that isn't a solution I can run with.

Comment: Probably best if you have all the code in a codepen or jsfiddle so we can diagnose the issue, but I'm guessing there's an overflow: hidden at play here. I've been dealing with this very same issue myself and our fix is to put something in like this that doesn't depend on scrolling: http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/

Comment: @NathanielFlick thanks for the advice! I managed to figure this one out but I bookmarked your link for future reference.

Comment: Cool what was the answer?

Comment: @NathanielFlick I had some code that fixed the header to the top of the page while scrolling, and the dropdown was absolutely positioned for mobile devices. I removed the position: fixed from the header container and I could properly scroll the navigation again.